# Fragment Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

Im creating an app that retrieve a data in sqlite. First, there's no problem but when i try to transfer it in fragment, i was not able to retrieve the data and i got an error. This is my first time in using fragment so i dont have an idea on my error.

```
public class Home_SpecialOffer extends Fragment {

    Context context;
    DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    ListView lvhome;
    List<TeaModel> GetHomeTea;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        context = container.getContext();

        try{
            dbhelper.createDataBase();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            dbhelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GetHomeTea = dbhelper.getHomeTea();
        lvhome = (ListView) container.findViewById(R.id.home_list);
        lvhome.setAdapter(new ViewAdapterHomeList());

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_special,null);


    }

    public class ViewAdapterHomeList extends BaseAdapter {

        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ViewAdapterHomeList() {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return GetHomeTea.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_home,null);
            }

            final TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.home_name);
            final TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.home_price);
            name.setText(GetHomeTea.get(position).getname());
            price.setText(GetHomeTea.get(position).getprice());

            Button btnbuy = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnbuy);
            btnbuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),GetHomeTea.get(position).getname()+" IS NOT YET AVAILABLE!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference and it is in this line :lvhome.setAdapter(new ViewAdapterHomeList());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this one ?

You need to **set view** for **Fragment layout**:

```
 @Nullable
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        context = container.getContext();

        try{
            dbhelper.createDataBase();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            dbhelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GetHomeTea = dbhelper.getHomeTea();
        lvhome = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_list);
        lvhome.setAdapter(new ViewAdapterHomeList());

        return rootView;


    }
```

You need to **pass** your **layout** file instead of `fragment_layout`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: it worked! thank you sir :) i'll accept your answer later since stackoverlow said i cant accept your answer in 8 min.

Comment: @A.Mallavo, Welcome :)